# JQGrid with Rich Text column

Tags: jqgrid

I'm building a JQGrid based solution for my SharePoint 2010 site and need help in incorporating a RichText inline editing functionality for one of the column. Most the examples are pertaining to plain text and didn't come across anything with RTE option.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to have a JQGrid Inline editing enabled for Rich Text Column?